# Using Split form to update data

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables, Tbl_Store1 & Tbl_Store2

I have one form (Frm_Data) that will populate from Tbl_Store1 or Tbl_Store2 based on an unbound text box called Txt_TblToUse.

Txt_TblToUse is a drop down field that only offers the user 2 choices. Store1 or store2.

After the user selects or changes Txt_TblsToUse I have the program set to update the data source to the correct table and then refresh, requery and repaint the form.

The frm_Data has a default view as a "Split Form"
The left side of the form is Form View
The Right side of the form is DataSheet View

The left side of the form (Form View) updates correctly
The right side of the form (DataSheet View) does not update to the new data.

If I right click on a header of one of the DataSheet view fields then chose to sort it, the data then re-populates with the correct data.

Is there a way to consistently update the data on the datasheet part of the form?

***************Code******************

```
Call TableToUse 'This will look in the Module1 and determine which table to use
```

*******************TableToUse Code*****************

```
Public Function TableToUse()
Form_Frm_Data.RecordSource = ""
Dim M_Month As Integer
M_Month = Form_Frm_Data.Txt_Month

Select Case Form_Frm_Data.Txt_TblToUse

  Case Is = "Store1"
      Form_Frm_Data.RecordSource = "Qry_Store1"
      Form_Frm_Data.Requery
   
   Case Is = "Tbl_Store2"
      Form_Frm_Data.RecordSource = "Qry_Store2"
      Form_Frm_Data.Requery

End Select

Dim db As String
db = ""
db = Form_Frm_Data.RecordSource
Form_Frm_Data.OrderBy = "TransactionDate ASC"
Form_Frm_Data.OrderBy = "TransactionDate DES"
Form_Frm_Data.Txt_DB = db
Form_Frm_Data.Recalc
Form_Frm_Data.Refresh
Form_Frm_Data.Repaint
Form_Frm_Data.ID.ColumnHidden = True

End Function
```

Comment: Why have 2 tables instead of one table with a field for storeID and apply filter criteria? Works for me. DataSheet immediately reflects filter.

Comment: I tested setting RecordSource to different table and the DataSheet immediately reflects the change - without Refresh, Repaint, Requery.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  To answer the 1st question about why two tables.  I actually have 12 stores but did not want to complicate the question.
The second answer.  I am not sure why yours works, I have tried with and without the three R's and all combinations of them.  

I seem to recall about 2 years ago when I first wrote the small program that there was a "bug" in access when it comes to split view DataSheet but I could not find any info today when I searched.  I may have phrased the question differently then.

Comment: Still recommend only 1 table. Since cannot replicate issue, cannot advise solution.